Closed XML - skip hidden cells?
I have a number of cells that are conditionally hidden (values visible in formula box but not displayed on sheet)depending on how the sheet is filled out. I want to skip parsing those values
Simplified sample:
foreach (var row in nonEmptyDataRows)
    bcd.AttributeName = (row.Cell(FarmAttribColNum).GetString() == "") ? null : (row.Cell(FarmAttribColNum).GetString());
    bcd.AttributeValue = (row.Cell(ValueColNum).GetString() == "") ? null : (row.Cell(ValueColNum).GetString());

So if one or the other of those cells is hidden, I don't want to parse them.
Unsure if there's a flag or check I can do to check if the field is hidden?
